# How to call a function in kendo

Tags: javascript, highcharts, kendo-ui

I would like to format mt x axis label via a calling a method as follows:

```
xAxis: {
   labels: {
     template: "#=  shortLabels(value) #"
      },
}


function shortLabels(value) {
    var strValue = kendo.toString(value)
    strValue = strValue + "";
    strValue = strValue.substring(1)
    return strValue;
}
```

However I am getting

> shortLabels is not defined error

basically it does not call that method.

http://jsfiddle.net/3yhbyy2g/31/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your function in a kendo-template. Isn't that beauty, you know, but works:

```
<script id="labelTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    #
    var strValue = kendo.toString(value)
    strValue = strValue + "";
    strValue = strValue.substring(1);
    #
    #= strValue #
</script>
```

and in the chart property:

```
labels: {
    template: kendo.template($("#labelTemplate").html())
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3yhbyy2g/32/).

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. Is there a way to make it in method? What I actually want is to make all X axis positive (+x,0,+x) http://jsfiddle.net/3yhbyy2g/36/

Comment: Any idea of the following questionhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/30144782/tooltip-with-multiple-parameters-in-kendo-ui